# How can I repeat a single column across each row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

**Context**:

I have a small piece of code that I wrote to visualise some binary numbers. It's a self contained HTML file that should work in the browser.

**Output**:

[image]

**Question**:

- How can I show the "Input" block (`.input-block` div) in each row of this flexbox layout?
- Is this achievable using Flexbox?

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
height: 80vh;
}
.block {
padding: 15px;
flex: 0 1 150px;
}
.input-block {
border: 1px solid black;
}
.block:hover {
background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}
.row {
padding: 10px;
text-align: right;
color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
letter-spacing: 1.4px;
}
.row:first-child {
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
background-color: burlywood;
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
background-color: rgb(255, 241, 219);
}
.row-head:nth-child(even) {
background-color: rgb(205, 255, 200);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>

<script type="module">
import { html, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html?module';

function main() {
    const arr = new Array(32).fill(0).map((x, i) => i);
    const elements = arr.map(x => getBinaryAssociates(x));
    let state = { elements }
    display(state);
}

/**
 * @param { { elements: ReturnType<typeof getBinaryAssociates>[] } } state
 */
function display(state) {
    const root = document.getElementById("root");

    /** @type {(_: typeof state) => any} */
    const tmpl = (state) => html`<div class="container">
        ${getHeaderBlockTmpl()}
        ${state.elements.map(getItemBlockTmpl)}
        <div>`;

    render(tmpl(state), root);
}

function getHeaderBlockTmpl() {
    return html`<div class="block input-block">
        <div class="row row-head">Input</div>
        ${FUNCTIONS.map(x => html`<div class="row row-head">${x.toString()}</div>`)}
        </div>`;
}

function getItemBlockTmpl(item) {
    return html`<div class="block">
        <div class="row">
            ${numToString(item.input)} ➡ ${item.binary}
        </div>
        ${item.outputs.map(x => html`<div class="row">
            ${x.value} ➡ ${x.binary}
            </div>`)}
    </div>`;
}

const FUNCTIONS = [
    x => x + 1,
    x => x - 1,
    x => x & (x - 1),
    x => ~x + 1,
    x => -(x + 1),
    x => ~x,
];

function numToString(n) {
    return n.toString();
}

function getBinaryAssociates(number) {
    const binary = (x) => (x >>> 0).toString(2).slice(-6).padStart(6, '0');

    let res = FUNCTIONS
        .map(x => ({
            function: x,
            value: numToString(x(number)),
            binary: binary(x(number)),
        }));

    let result = res.reduce((acc, n) => {
        acc.outputs.push(n);
        return acc;
    }, {
        input: number,
        binary: binary(number),
        /** @type {typeof res} */
        outputs: [],
    });

    return result;
}


function init() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        main();
    });
}

init();
</script>
```

Comment: can you clarify *What's the best way to show the "Input" block in each row of this flex-box layout?*  `.block{border:solid;}`?   the `.row` is wrapped into columns here . Is Input `.row-head`?   every thing seems shown and readable ...

Comment: if you want to put the input block in front of each row, this is not possible with flexbox because you have to duplicate your content

Comment: @G-Cyr - is that reformatting edit necessary? Honestly, I find that this makes it harder to read and a bit confusing.

Comment: @G-Cyr - Also with respect to your clarifications, I changed the code slightly and extracted that to an `getHeaderTmpl` function. That's the part I basically want to be repeated. I merged the code again into one block though, please let me know if you absolutely want them to be separated :) (I found the previous formatting to be difficult to read nullifying the advantage of "Snippet" view that you seem to have added on)

Comment: i turned it into a snippet , so anyone can visualize the output and can  copy it into an answser to demonstrate it. I still do not understand what output you expect beside what you have. Probably my english not good enough ;)

Comment: Ok, let me try to convert it again, trying to retain original formatting. And will mark the block to be repeated here.

Comment: @G-Cyr - Done. Turned into snippet, and added `input-block` class to it. Also, found that the snippet editor for some reason thinks the code isn't formatted correctly even though it is.. But had to wrap it in "```" - for whatever reason, this seems to bypass that check.

Comment: You're using flex wrap, the content may wrap at any moment and css doesn't have a way to track that. so we can't know before hand many rows there will be because it's based on the viewport, this is all too complicated and specific for just css, You're already using javascript why not add the logic to align everything.